# Multiple timers in openGL

Tags: c++, opengl, glut

Can i have multiple timer functions in openGL? I want to generate some obstacles every 2 seconds as well as having my game close with exit(0) after 1 minute. Can i have each in a separate function or what?

Comment: OpenGL doesn't have timers.

Comment: Show what you tried, your question has no code, nor it's a clear question.

Comment: Are you talking about `glutTimerFunc()` callbacks?

Answer (score 2):

OpenGL does not supply any sort of timing functionality. It only draws geometry. You can likely use your operating system's built-in timer functions to do the timing and supply whatever geometry is appropriate to your OpenGL drawing code when your timer goes off.